# What is this ghost object?

Tags: objects

I don't even know what this old part I deleted clipping into my object is doing here but I can't get rid of it without deleting my whole object.
And it doesn't show up in edit mode?
What even is this?
[image]

[Here's the file](https://pasteall.org/blend/6c85fdf75aa44feca21ae9c02603eb6c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hidden in *Edit* mode. Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to reveal it and you can delete it.

Comment: Man I'm an idiot I don't even remember when I hid it